# Laravel как ставить разные страницы на один url

Tags: laravel

Надо сделать так что бы если пользователь авторизован ссылка / возвращала один вид, а если нет то совсем другой, как это сделать в laravel?

Comment: в чём проблема сделать разные страницы?

Comment: просто это не совсем удобно и логично, так как должна быть главная для авторизованного пользователя и для не авторизованного.

Comment: middleware сделайте и по нему чекайте кого куда и как перекидывать (какую view подключать)

Comment: Вы бы хоть небольшой код выложили, чтобы понять в чем разница между этими страницами.

Comment: Всем спасибо, я решил через middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Точно также, как и в resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php:

```
{{-- Authentication Links --}}
@guest

    {{-- Links 1 --}}

@else

    {{-- Links 2 --}}

@endguest
{{-- Authentication Links --}}
```